# Writing to USB Drive from Android Phone

Tags: android, storage, external

So I've searched around on the internet a lot while trying to find the answer to this, but so far to no avail. I have a program that functions perfectly on the S4 that at one point writes and reads from a USB drive. Correcting for the fact that the location that USB drives show up at is different from phone to phone, the same program does not function on a motorola Moto X that I just purchased. Looking at the LogCat, it appears that there is a permission error when attempting to write to the USB, yet I've specified permissions for reading and writing to external storage in the Manifest file.

I've noticed that when looking at the LogCat for my S4 after running the program, that samsung has a special implementation of the normal OS for dealing with USB's under the tag KiesUsbObserver, and I'm wondering if that's handling a couple of extra functions that the Moto X can't automatically deal with.

Has anyone ran into a similar problem?

Logcat for S4

```
09-17 11:24:37.506: W/KiesUsbObserver(777): getUsbMode() -> sys.usb.config :       mass_storage,adb
09-17 11:24:37.506: W/KiesUsbObserver(777): getUsbMode() -> bCDFS: true
09-17 11:24:37.546: E/MTPRx(27958): In MtpReceiverandroid.hardware.usb.action.USB_STATE
09-17 11:24:37.546: E/MTPRx(27958): check value of boot_completed is1
09-17 11:24:37.546: E/MTPRx(27958): check booting is completed_sys.boot_completed
09-17 11:24:37.546: E/MTPRx(27958): Sd-Card path/storage/extSdCard
09-17 11:24:37.546: E/MTPRx(27958): Status for mount/Unmount :mounted
09-17 11:24:37.546: E/MTPRx(27958): SDcard is  available
09-17 11:24:37.546: E/MTPRx(27958): The value of first_boot is  1
09-17 11:24:37.546: E/MTPRx(27958): [ 662] The value of first_boot is  1NORMAL SEQUENCE 
09-17 11:24:37.546: W/MTPRx(27958): value of connected istrue
09-17 11:24:37.546: W/MTPRx(27958): value of configured isfalse
09-17 11:24:37.546: W/MTPRx(27958): value of mtpEnabled isfalse
09-17 11:24:37.546: W/MTPRx(27958): value of ptpEnabled isfalse
09-17 11:24:37.546: E/MTPRx(27958): Received USB_STATE with sdCardLaunch = 0
09-17 11:24:37.546: E/MTPRx(27958): tethering is started and mtp is not running so  returning
```

Logcat for Moto X

```
09-17 11:34:19.053: W/MountService(842): getVolumeState(/storage/usbdisk_1.1.1): Unknown volume
09-17 11:34:19.053: E/VoldConnector(842): Error handling '605 Volume usbdisk_1.1.1 /storage/usbdisk_1.1.1 state changed from 0 (No-Media) to 2 (Pending)': java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
09-17 11:34:19.053: W/MountService(842): getVolumeState(/storage/usbdisk_1.1.1): Unknown volume
09-17 11:34:19.054: E/VoldConnector(842): Error handling '605 Volume usbdisk_1.1.1 /storage/usbdisk_1.1.1 state changed from 2 (Pending) to 1 (Idle-Unmounted)': java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
09-17 11:34:19.061: W/MountService(842): getVolumeState(/storage/usbdisk_1.1.1): Unknown volume
09-17 11:34:19.061: E/VoldConnector(842): Error handling '605 Volume usbdisk_1.1.1  /storage/usbdisk_1.1.1 state changed from 1 (Idle-Unmounted) to 3 (Checking)': java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
09-17 11:34:19.404: E/Trace(6489): error opening trace file: Permission denied (13)
09-17 11:34:19.731: E/(6489): netstack: LIB_MGR - Error loading lib spl_proc_plugin.so
09-17 11:34:19.731: E/(6489): netstack: STAT_HUB - Failed to load plugin:  spl_proc_plugin.so
09-17 11:34:19.732: E/(6489): netstack:  STAT_HUB - App com.metago.astro isn't supported
```